# Creating table with stacked variable names

Tags: tables, formatting

I am having an issue with creating a regression table where I don't want the variable name to be super long and want it to sort of stack. For example, I want a variable name such as "first second third" to write "third" below "first second" without generate a new row and leaving an entire row of spaces. My table follows the current format:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \hline
& & Data1 & & & Data2 & \\
VARIABLES & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
x1 & coef1 & coef2 & coef3 & coef4 & coef5 & coef6 \\
first second & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\
third & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

If I were to leave the variable as "first second third" I cannot fit all 6 specifications on the page. I hope the above working example is sufficient, if not please let me know.

Edit: I essentially want to the coefficient, in this case "no" to be centered on the stacked names. Not sure how to word it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Take a look at the `makecell` package.  It allows for line breaks in standard columns, with the `\makecell`   and `\thead` commands. Their contents can have a common formatting, and it is centred by default, both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two suggestions. The first one is based on manual linebreaks using the [makecell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package that was already [mentioned by Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500662/creating-table-with-stacked-variable-names#comment1264587_500662) while the second one used an `m` type column and automatic (or potentially also manual) linebreaks:

I have also replaced the `\hline`s by rules from the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and added some vertical white space as a guide to the eye. In the third table, I have also used `\multicolumn` and some `\cmidrule`s.

Depending on the width of your table and the length of your variable names, you might also benefit from the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \toprule
& & Data1 & & & Data2 & \\
VARIABLES & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \midrule
x1 & coef1 & coef2 & coef3 & coef4 & coef5 & coef6 \\
\makecell[lc]{first\\ second\\ third} & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.1cm}cccccc} \toprule
& & Data1 & & & Data2 & \\
VARIABLES & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \midrule
x1 & coef1 & coef2 & coef3 & coef4 & coef5 & coef6 \\ \addlinespace
first second third & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\ \addlinespace
first \newline second third & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.1cm}cccccc} \toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Data1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Data2}  \\ \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
VARIABLES & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \midrule
x1 & coef1 & coef2 & coef3 & coef4 & coef5 & coef6 \\ \addlinespace
first second third & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\ \addlinespace
first \newline second third & no & no & yes & no & no & yes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add `@{}` at the beginning and end of the table preamble to remove the side bearings.

Comment: @Sveinung: Thanks for your suggestion. Personally, I prefer the slight indentation but if the OP wants to remove it, they can easily add `@{}`.

Comment: Side bearing are spaces for vertical rules, Traditional book type tabular has no side bearings, as mentioned in [booktabs manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf). However, I have taken note of your preference and will stop nagging you :)

Comment: @Sveinung: That's definitely an interesting point of view ("Side bearing are spaces for vertical rules") that did not yet come to my mind. I've skimmed the booktabs manual but could not find an explicit suggestion to remove thouse side bearings (apart from all of  the examples using `@{}`). As I seem to have failed to notice this information could you please help me out and add a page/section number? By the way, why did you revert your edit?

Comment: The purpose of the side bearing I have picked up from some other places. The booktabs manual describes formal book style tabular, without side bearing by example, and has also description how to remove them in longtables (see section 5). In addition, I worked several years in the Ministry of Finance in Norway, where tabular never were typeset with side bearings (and still does not).

Comment: I reverted the edit because your had a layout according to your preference. When I revert home from vacation, I will see if Bringhurst as recommendation regarding tabular layout. I see that @Bernhard some places has chosen a compromise. I replace the side bearing with a thin space, i.e. `@{\,}` (or `@{\thinspace}`).